# recv() function returns -1

Tags: sockets, dll, network-programming, windows-phone-8.1

This (-1) is not on the fail return code list.

Things going on like this,
On a WP8.1 SL project,

I'm calling a set of socket functions on a native DLL.

- WSAStartup() succeeed,
- GethostbyName() succeed,
- Create socket and connect() succeed,
- send() succeed,

But recv() failed, and returns -1

All the functions works well on emulator,
But only recv() returns -1 on device.

Did any of you have any idea why? :-P

PS: There's no problem when it was called in a lib on WP8.1 WRT.
    But later I need to use WP8.1 SL, so I build it into a dll. :-P

Comment: `recv` returns -1 on any error. Try calling `WSAGetLastError` to get the error code and figure out the reason.

Comment: getLastError returns 10060, Connection timed out.
But there's no such issue on sent().
I couldn't figure out why. :-P

Comment: Don't use code formatting for text that isn't code.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I fixed it.

Because I didn't setup the WiFi on phone.